# How to set mat-slider color dynamics

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to change mat-slider color dynamic. I have a app where user can select any color from color palate and I want to show that color as a slider color.

I know you can add custom color name in color attribute, but in my case color name is not fixed. It can be any color from color palate.

`<mat-slider [(ngModel)]="lifeArea.weighting" [name]="lifeArea.title" thumbLabel="true" color="green" thumbLabel min="0" max="10" step="1"></mat-slider>`

In this I will get color code in `lifeArea.color`

Answer (score 1):

As I know you cannot set color as you want. The mat-slider color should be a `ThemePalette` according to the [Angular Material documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/slider/api).

To do this Angular Material should support additional colors outside primary, accent, warn but it is not the case.

I think the only option you have is to define a css stylesheet overriding mat-silder style to set your background color:

1. Define a css variable containing your default mat-slider color
2. Set all needed css attributes with this variable
3. Change the value of your css variable when color change

Answer (score 0):

While using material components,
Color attribute is only accepts three colors i.e. primary, warn and accent which are default in your theme.

If you wanted to assign custom color to material component you can assign class to it and give required css for that color.

In your case, color is dynamically populating.
So you can achieve this by using ngStyle directive.

Comment: style directive will not useful, as mat-slider is not assigning color to host component, but it assign to its child div class, and with style directive its not useful.

Comment: Yes you are correct. I tried lots of solutions after reading your comment but after lots of try and error process, I came to this conclusion : You have to write your own theme palette. Because mat-slider is accepting color from only theme palette .

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

**HTML**

```
<mat-slider [(ngModel)]="lifeArea.weighting" [name]="lifeArea.title" 
thumbLabel="true" [color]="lifeArea.color" thumbLabel min="0" max="10" step="1"></mat-slider>
```

You need to do **property binding** with `color` attribute.

Comment: This is the way you can have dynamic color but lifeArea.color should be defined in codebase

Comment: and whats wrong with it? You can always provide simple string in markup.

Comment: this wont work. color attribute wont take direct color code, this should be string.